# Raspberry Pi 4 refuses to boot from USB (128GB)

Tags: usb, boot, pi-4, boot-issues

[image]

OK, Raspberry Pi does not boot from Raspbian USB...

Comment: is it a USB "thumb drive", or perhaps a HDD or SSD on a USB to SATA, or something else?

Comment: OK reboot footage https://sv2.fastupload.co/files/07-2021/02/mp4/FastUpload-final_60ddf7f28925d8006994bd3f_842673-1625160016.mp4

Comment: is it a USB "thumb drive", or perhaps a HDD or SSD on a USB to SATA, or something else?

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 0):

Did you burn it directly on USB stick or cloned from microSD?
I first installed Raspberry OS from microSD and then I used "clone microSD" from the Applications menu to transfer all to USB stick. Then in raspi-config I changed to boot from USB first. All went ok.

Comment: I used bash terminal and cloned the microsd a1! raspbian: sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=/dev/sda and it took 12.1 hours to do so it took half a day

Comment: also, want me to flash raspberry pi UEFI firmware? If yes then give me instructions to get the USB booting and I used raspi-config to boot it (it is USB 2 128GB)

Comment: dd does not care if you have data or not - if you use the cloning tool from Raspberry OS it will take minutes as it makes magic: prepares partitions on new card, formats properly the card and then it only copies the data - if you have 32GB microSD with 2GB in use dd will take age - it will copy 32GB, clone tool will take less then preparing coffee